# How to access value from a consecutive locations with double pointer using memcpy

Tags: c, pointers

As we see in the dipiction below

[image: memory map]

There are two memory blocks low(250 x unsigned int) and high(250 x unsigned int)
The High block contains the values and the low block contains the address

So I have created an Array of pointer from low block to high block
and accessing this array of pointer using another pointer(**OutputOffsetAddress) which traverse through the low block deferences the address and fetches the value

So If I wanted to read a value straight away from an address (without all this pointers) I did it this way

```
Read(unsigned offset, void *buffer, unsigned size)
{
  memcpy(buffer, memBase + offset, size);
}
```

But now I have a double pointer which I want to deference it and get the value.

One of the approach is

```
unsigned int a[250];
for (int x = 0; x < 250; x++)
{
    a[x] = **outputOffsetAddress;
    outputOffsetAddress++;
}
```

**But I have a time constraint of 10 ms to read all 250 locations.**

Will the above solution work
if not How I can do the same thing using a `memcpy`

Comment: 10ms seems like plenty of time to read 250 memory locations. What platform are you on?

Comment: How about `a[x] = *outputOffsetAddress[x];`?

Comment: @th33lf: That is 500 locations, not 250; each data read requires a pointer read.

Comment: The operation you read is a “gather” operation, a term commonly paired as a scatter-gather operation. In general, it is a bad operation for hardware because the processor cannot predict the location for the next read (because it is controlled by contents of stored pointer, which the processor does not know the value of, rather than by consecutively increasing addresses, which a processor can predict), so it cannot do any prefetching. Gather operations can also be very bad for cache. However, the operation you describe is small…

Comment: … All the data would fit in cache in many systems. There may be no way to improve the core loop `for (int x = 0; x < 250; ++x) a[x] = *outputOffsetAddress[x];`. (If there is some pattern to the pointers, that might be exploited to gain some improvement.) If the data is entirely in cache already, some processors will execute that code optimally, and there may be no improvement available. If the data is not in cache, it might be possible to improve performance by prefetching the 500 words so they are loaded efficiently.

Comment: All of this depends on hardware characteristics. You would have to specify the hardware you are using, and people would have to delve into its various characteristics to analyze further—how well does it handle random memory loads versus sequential, how long do things take compare to your 10 ms goal, and so on.

Comment: I am using On-time RTOS on a Trenton Industrial Computer